# Erro ao carregar página php no site online

Tags: php, javascript, html5, json

Fiz todo o site no meu computador testando com o xamp. Porém quando fui colocar online, apareceram alguns problemas ao carregar 3 páginas de acesso ao banco que são parecidas.

```
<?php 
require_once('db.class.php');

$objdb = new db();
$link = $objdb->conecta_mysql();

$sql =  "SELECT DISTINCT categoria FROM produtos ORDER BY categoria";
if($resultado = mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    if($resultado->num_rows > 0){
        while($linha = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)){
            $vetor[] = $linha;
        }
        echo json_encode($vetor);
    }else{
        echo json_encode('');
    }

}else{
    echo json_encode("errobanco");
}
```

?>

No navegador aparece o seguinte erro:

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE crud/carregar_cat.php:1
```

OBS: Estou usando um host free para testar.

Comment: Pelo celular, ele entra normal? Usando o 4G

Comment: Entra também não, já testei.

Comment: Você tá usando porta 80?

Comment: Tem algum antivírus instalado ?

Comment: O caminho para `db.class.php` está correto no servidor?

Comment: O caminho está correto sim, esse arquivo está na mesma pasta da conexão com o banco.